# Does it make sense to have a wiki page for recursion equations

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Questions like

> analyze a time complexity of the following recursion T(n) = T(something) + f(n)

these questions receive mixed feedback. Some people eagerly advocate them to be closes/moved to math/cs site and some questions got many reasonable attention. Also these questions do not require programming, the analysis of algorithms is a required topic in almost all CS programs. Many of these problems are posted in [recurrence tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recurrence).

Recently I wanted to refresh my skills and solved many of these problems. The problem that I saw is that some of the questions are duplicates of each other and many of them are really similar.

My question is: should these types of questions be allowed here? And if they should does it make sense to have a wiki question and when someone post a question about finding a time complexity of the recurrence they will be redirected to a wiki page where a person will see a list of already asked and answered questions like:

**recurrence for a master method**

- T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
- T(n) = 3T(n/4) + log n
- .....

**recurrence that consist of many calls to a sub recurrence function**

- T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + 1
- T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + log n
- ...

**recurrences with a square root**

- T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + log n
- T(n) = 2T(sqrt(n)) + 1
- ...

**something else**

Do you think this makes sense or is this useless?

Comment: So stopping localized questions? That seems like what you're doing...

Comment: @Zizouz212 hoping that before posting `how to solve T(n) = T(n/3) + 1` a person will try to look and find the similar question T(n) = T(n/2) + 1, look how people solved it and only if he was not able to solve with the hint he would ask a new question.

Comment: Why make a wiki here on SO if these questions should be asked on math/cs?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan why are you so sure they have to asked on math/cs? I have not seen a definite answer that these questions belong there (and if you look closely at my question you will see that I asked it). Math does not really look suitable for this needs, because in math they do not analyze algorithms and the fact that someone has to use formulas and logarithm does not actually mean that it belongs to math. CS - I am not so sure, may be it belongs there may be it does not.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you did. It was a bit hard to parse the question... I'm not a big fan of answers that are a list of links though. And I'm not sure how you'd ask an on-topic question that would result in that answer... Maybe it would be suitable for an external site that links to SO? Something like http://sopython.com/canon/ ?